# Search a certain value in a cursor in multiple fields

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I am trying to find the phrase REQUIRE!!! in certain fields (PROJ_NAME, MAJOR_LITH, OWNER_ID) in a feature class. If it has the value REQUIRE!!! it will send user an email. If there are no value that is REQUIRE!!! it will update another feature class.

I got the updating part but could not figure out the searching field part. I can't figure out what is wrong with the cursor part.

```
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Strip_Geology_BOB6, ['PROJ_NAME', 'MAJOR_LITH', 'OWNER_ID']) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    value = ['REQUIRED!!!']
    if row in value:
        MESSAGE_REGION = "From: %s\r\n" % FROM + "To: %s\r\n" % TO + "Subject: %s\r\n" % "Strip Geology - Missing Required Fields" + "\r\n" + "Auto generated Message.\n\rPlease fix required fields in Strip Geology Feature Class"
        server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
        server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE_REGION)
        server.quit()
    else:
        arcpy.Select_analysis (Strip_Geology_BOB6, Strip_Geology_BOB6_Select, "DATAUPLOAD = 'No'")
        arcpy.Append_management(Strip_Geology_BOB6_Select, SDE_Strip_Geology, "TEST", "", "")
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(Strip_Geology_BOB6, "DATAUPLOAD", "\"Yes\"", "PYTHON", "")
        arcpy.Delete_management (Strip_Geology_BOB6_Select)
```

Comment: If you knock out everything in the `if` and `else` blocks, then just run this script, you'll have a better chance of locating the issue.  Add a print statement or two.  Restrict the input to one table with one field and two rows, and see if your "row in value" test works.  I'd expect you'd need to test each of the row elements, probably with the `any` operator.  Please [Edit] the question to make the description match the code, vis-a-vis the the string for which you are searching. Once you have the logic right, you'll need further work on messing with the selection set while in a cursor.

Comment: row is returning a list of cell values from the cursor and will always evaluate false the way you have it written.  You want...if value in row:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic isn't quite right. I'm assuming that the field will be only `REQUIRED!!!` and not something like `VALUE IS REQUIRED!!!`. Here's how you check to see if something is in a tuple:

```
>>> tup1 = ("REQUIRED!!!", "Not", "maybe")
>>> tup2 = ("REQUIRED??", "Not", "maybe")
>>> "REQUIRED!!!" in tup1
True
>>> "REQUIRED!!!" in tup2
False
>>>
```

So:

```
value = 'REQUIRED!!!'
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Strip_Geology_BOB6, ['PROJ_NAME', 'MAJOR_LITH', 'OWNER_ID']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        #check if value is in any of the fields
        if value in row:
            MESSAGE_REGION = "From: %s\r\n" % FROM + "To: %s\r\n" % TO + "Subject: %s\r\n" % "Strip Geology - Missing Required Fields" + "\r\n" + "Auto generated Message.\n\rPlease fix required fields in Strip Geology Feature Class"
            server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER)
            server.sendmail(FROM, TO, MESSAGE_REGION)
            server.quit()
        else:
            arcpy.Select_analysis (Strip_Geology_BOB6, Strip_Geology_BOB6_Select, "DATAUPLOAD = 'No'")
            arcpy.Append_management(Strip_Geology_BOB6_Select, SDE_Strip_Geology, "TEST", "", "")
            arcpy.CalculateField_management(Strip_Geology_BOB6, "DATAUPLOAD", "\"Yes\"", "PYTHON", "")
            arcpy.Delete_management (Strip_Geology_BOB6_Select)
```